# How do identical forms using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I have number of posts displayed (similar to Facebook) on a website, each post includes a form to permit a reply as shown below.

```
<form class="is-pulled-right formElem">
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{@post.id}}">
<div class="field is-grouped">
  <p class="control is-expanded">
    <input class="input" type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Reply">
  </p>
  <p class="control">
    <input type="submit" class="button is-info" value="Reply">
  </p>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript code I use to post the form data.

```
let replyForm = document.querySelector('.formElem');

replyForm.onsubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

let response = await fetch('/post/reply', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: new FormData(replyForm)
});
```

}

On first submission, the form is posted correctly to "/post/reply", as a POST. However on subsequent submissions the data is posted as GET and does not go to "/post/reply". What do I need to do have each of the forms recognized individually?

Answer (score 0):

you need to get all the form elements and bind the event.

```
let replyForms = document.querySelectorAll('.formElem');
replyForms.forEach(form => {
    form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let response = await fetch('/post/reply', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: new FormData(form)
        });
    })
})
```

Comment: Just a tweak to your code and it's working, The only thing I had to change was "form.addEventListener to form.onsubmit = async" because await is only valid inside an async functions. Thanks for your help.